# Grabbing the first visit in a month for people in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have this query which shows the number of Unique Visitors visited a website for each month:

```
WITH MyStore AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    accountid AS "AID"
    ,visitstarttime
    ,datekey
    FROM access.data
    WHERE datekey >= '2022-12-19'
    AND user_server = 'app.mystore.com'
    AND accountid <> ' '
)
SELECT
YEAR(visitstarttime) AS Year
,MONTH(visitstarttime) AS Month
--,DAY(visitstarttime) AS Day
,COUNT(AID) AS MyStoreVisits
FROM MyStore
GROUP BY YEAR(visitstarttime), MONTH(visitstarttime)--, DAY(visitstarttime)
ORDER BY YEAR(visitstarttime), MONTH(visitstarttime)--, DAY(visitstarttime)
```

And the query works great! However I want to try to filter it down by a certain date. Is there a way I can pull in the day to when a user first visited for that month?

I tried this but it doesn't seem.
`RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(visitstarttime), MONTH(visitstarttime), DAY(visitstarttime)) AS rn`
This line of code will bring in:

| Month | Day | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 27 | 1 |
| 01 | 2 | 1 |
| 01 | 3 | 1 |

However, I want the first visit of every month to be marked as 1, and the second visit as 2 and so on and so fourth. I also tried ROW_NUMBER and that returned the same results.

Comment: I don't think you need to GROUP BY X, Y if you also ORDER BY X, Y.

Comment: Do you want the first time a specific user visited each month or the first visit, by any user, in the month?

Comment: @NickW I want the first visit by all users for each month. I'm looking to test the query though by drilling down to 1 user. For example, if I visit on Christmas Eve, Christmas Day and March 16, I only want to see my visit on Christmas Eve and in March 16

Comment: If you want the first visit in the month by any visitor then PARTITION by year and month. If you want the first visit in the month for each visitor then PARTITION by year, month and visitor